# How to solve 'failed linking file resources' error?

Tags: android

I'm getting a build error: 'failed linking file resources' in Android Studio. How do I solve this?

Comment: Show your `activity_main.xml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginBottom="75dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="400sp"
    android:removeView=""
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

`android:removeView` doesn't exist. Remove that line.

Answer (score 0):

there is some thing wrong in one of the XML files

you can go back and check your recently added/changed XML

for me it was spelling mistake(vible instead of visible)

```
      <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/prog_bar"
            style="@style/ProgressBar.Green"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            **android:visibility="vible"**/>
```